# Change Logo in WordPress when a WooCommerce category is clicked or opened

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have been thinking and searching about this
But i can't find the results..

Is it possible that if you click on a category "men" in a WP/ Woocommerce Shop that it will show a different logo then the main logo?

Like if you go to http://ninethemes.net/avano/wordpress/1/shop/#

And you will click a category like "men' that the Logo will change?

So yes, how can i do that the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or PHP. In jQuery detect a click on a category and then change the logo. For example by naming the logos the same as the category name.
In PHP you would need to edit header.php: detect which category you are on and replace the img with the one you want.
I would go for the PHP option.